# Adding properties to existing doctrine entities

Tags: php, doctrine

I have the following design problem: I have two projects which both use doctrine to manage their entities. Both projects work on similar entities (most of them are in fact equal). I thought now it would be the best to write a library which contains the core entities used by both projects.

But this gives me more headaches than I first thought. Lets give you the following example, I have an entity

```
class Entity {
    ... a lot of managed properties used in both projects
}
```

then in project A i use exactly this entity, in project B my entity looks a little bit different:

```
class Entity {
    ... a lot of managed properties used in both projects
    ... one managed property only used in project B
}
```

Now if I declare Entity in my library I could extend it in my project B to add the additional property. But then the question is how to do it with doctrine. If I declare the entity in the library managed I can't easily declare the derived class as managed too in project B. On the other hand if I don't declare it managed in the library I won't be able to have associations containing the entity (which is in my case very important, I have a lot of associations across all my entities).

How should I handle such a situation? Writing the whole entity structure two times in both projects? It doesn't seem the right thing to do for me, but I can't think of another solution.

Comment: In that case the database associated with project A would contain columns (or even whole tables) which it doesn't use at all. By the way this was just an example it may also be that an entity in project A has some properties which do not exist in project B and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [traits](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.traits.php) that would contain sets of annotated properties and their related methods. This would give you the possibility to have a common base on which you can build both sides independently.

The down side is that both objects would not have a common interface, some of their internals would be the same but you would not be able to tell from the outside. A way to go around this would be to write an [`interface`](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.interfaces.php) that exposes the methods you need to operate with those entities in your common library. The common `trait` could then take care of implementing that interface.

---

**Edit:** As you pointed out, traits are not very helpful if we are dealing with associations as you cannot override the `targetEntity` of an association with `AssociationOverride` annotation. That being said, by searching about that particular topic, I stumbled on the `ResolveTargetEntityListener` which might be the tool you were searching for.

The official documentation has [a detailed page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html) about how to use it (if you are using Symfony, there is [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) as well). As explained in the documentation, thanks to that utility, you can have relationships between entities based on abstract classes or interfaces that would be resolved at runtime.

### ResolveTargetEntityListener use with abstract classes

Here is a working example with abstract classes with the annotation `MappedSuperClass`:

AppBundle/Model/AbstractA.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
abstract class AbstractA
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="string")
     */
    private $text;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Model\AbstractB") */
    private $b;
}
```

AppBundle/Model/AbstractB.php

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
abstract class AbstractB
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="number", type="integer") */
    private $number;
}
```

AppBundle/Entity/A.php

```
/** @ORM\Entity() */
class A extends AbstractA {}
```

AppBundle/Entity/B.php

```
/** @ORM\Entity() */
class B extends AbstractB {}
```

And since I tested this with Symfony, I had to add the following in my config:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        resolve_target_entities:
            AppBundle\Model\AbstractA: AppBundle\Entity\A
            AppBundle\Model\AbstractB: AppBundle\Entity\B
```

When asking doctrine for a schema update, it outputs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, b_id INT DEFAULT NULL, text VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_E8B7BE43296BFCB6 (b_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE b (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, number INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT FK_E8B7BE43296BFCB6 FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b (id);
```

Comment: I also thought of that, but this doesn't solve the problem of associations. If I only have traits in my base library how do I annotate references to other entities?

Comment: Indeed, if you only have interfaces and no entities in your base library, this would not really work. Doctrine gives the possibility to override field association mapping as explained [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html). Maybe it could be of some help.

Comment: The AssociationOverride is no good either but I found about the `ResolveTargetEntityListener` utility that might be the right tool for the job. I updated my post to include it.

Comment: that sounds exactly what I searched for :), thanks a lot for the digging

Comment: Glad to help ;) Not sure if it fits with your use case, but I just added an example that uses abstract classes that I could test succesfully with Symfony just know.

Answer (score 1):

That is a common and actually really good question. Lots of people are in trouble with such issues, and we cannot say that there is one and only one right answer to that.

I experienced various solutions, and the best I could "use" is to duplicate the entity(ies) definition(s) in each project.

Why ?

Because it is indeed easier to maintain, and even if you have some migration strategies (e.g. with Doctrine migrations or whatever), your code, relying on a specific version of the entities, could break.
You can try to deal with that kind of issues with a tool for migration strategies (i'm kinda out of the subject), and I'd then recommend to store every property (even the ones that are project-specific) in your library.

But do this if you really need it. Is it a big deal for you to duplicate ? Sometimes, factoring everything is not a good idea.

If you duplicate the definitions, you'll also be able to only focus on properties that you really care about. This means that some properties that you don't care about can be omitted from your entities definition in each project.

Just ensure that you still have a strategy for your migrations, it's always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Duplicating the entities would be ok for me, but I also have some parts of the logic which are common in both projects and I planned to put this logic also in the common library. But this logic uses those common entities.

Since I try to stay object oriented and I am also using strict_types in php I can't use then the logic from the library in my projects since it operates on "different entities" if I duplicate the entities in the projects.

Comment: I also had the idea to don't manage any entities in the base library via doctrine and then inherit all my entities from those entities and use YAML to define the doctrine mappings instead of annotations. Is this a reasonable valid approach? I am quite used to annotations, but if this solves my problem I would switch to YAML.

Comment: Well you could, but I'm curious about your project duplicating the logic for given entities. IMO duplicating entities is OK, but heavy logic has to be challenged : can't you have a service by itself that's purpose would be to manage the domain ? We'd stick a bit more to single responsibility matters.

Comment: Yes I have services which manage the shared domains, but still, those services operate on the entities. If I duplicate now my entities in the sub projects the services from the base library operate on the wrong classes which breaks enforced type hints.

Comment: It's hard to evaluate what you'd have to duplicate, but if it is not so heavy, maybe it's still the path to follow, even for some logic. If you really need flexibility, you could have a base entity defined in a shared library, and some kind of a configuration that would permit you to extend your base entity in each project and make your library use your extended class. Beware though, it seems heavy, and overengineering is close.

Comment: Ok one idea how I could live with entity duplication would be to add an interface for each entity in the base library and all services only operate on those interfaces. Then my entities in the sub libraries can implement those interfaces. I think I will do it this way, all other options seam a little bit like a hack.

Comment: Sounds good ! Remember, try to make it as simple as possible ;-) If you need any extra help or an external point of view, feel free to keep me in touch.